# Postgres: ERROR: column d.adsrc does not exist

Tags: postgresql, docker

I have two containers in the Postgres docker and adminer

[image]

images:

[image]

But I have this error in admin could anyone help?
error:

```
ERROR: column d.adsrc does not exist
LINE 1: ...ormat_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod) AS full_type, d.adsrc AS...
```

Comment: The `adsrc` column was removed in Postgres 12. Looks like your admin tool is expecting an older version.

Comment: @Nick Barnes i install adminer lastest version,  
so i have to for an older version of postgress? 
Do you recommend any administrative version that works with postgress 12?

Comment: What are those two PNG files?  (If they're screenshots of terminals, please delete them and replace them with the actual text that's being printed out, if it's relevant to your question.)  Do you have a specific reason to think that column or table does exist?  Can you edit the question to include the code that's generating the error?

Comment: @David Maze png  one = containers in docker, two = images in docker

Comment: i put error,because he can not see my table in adminer

Comment: @Gabriel: The official tool is the command-line [`psql`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html). If you want a GUI, I think most people use [pgAdmin](https://www.pgadmin.org/).

Comment: @NickBarnes Hello thanks do you know how I can enable psql by command line in docker?

Comment: @Gabriel: Sorry, I don't understand. If you need help with something else, please post a new question.

Answer (score 22):

You are encountering this error because in Postgres v. 12, the `pg_attrdef.adsrc` column is [no longer being used](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/release-12.html).  There is [currently a patch for adminer](https://github.com/vrana/adminer/pull/367/commits/717d9e636e6eb654949a6ed16407ab7288ff5205), but has not been committed or scheduled for release.  If you wish you patch it yourself, just edit `pgsql.inc.php` and replace `d.adsrc` with `pg_get_expr(d.adbin, d.adrelid)`

Other clients like phpPgAdmin are encountering the same issue, though you should see updates getting released sometime soon.

[You may wish to use pgAdmin4](https://www.pgadmin.org/), as it seems to have a pretty recent release that includes fixes for v. 12 changes.