# PostgreSQL Delphi XE2 column pd.adsrc does not exists

Tags: postgresql, delphi-xe2

After upgrading postgreSQL 12 i'm getting ad.adsrc error.

Does anyone know how to patch it without upgradeing PgDAC?

My idea was creating tabel myself, but you can't...
`SELECT pg_get_expr(d.adbin, d.adrelid) as adsrc, * FROM pg_attrdef d;`

Comment: Try looking here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58789024/postgres-error-column-d-adsrc-does-not-exist/58798028#58798028

Comment: @richyen Sadly no help. PgDac in .exe which you install in computer. I beginner knowledge of Delphi and how to patch it.