# fixing orphaend Sequences in postgres-12

Tags: postgresql, sequence, pg-dump, postgresql-12

I'm trying to run `pg_dump` and it's failing due to a orphaned sequence.

`pg_dump -U db  --format=custom --compress=0 db`
`pg_dump: error: query to get data of sequence "non_existing_table_id_seq" returned 0 rows (expected 1)`

https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Fixing_Sequences

The above wiki page has some snippets which can be used to fix this issue, the last snippit does work to display the orphaned snippets.

```
select ns.nspname as schema_name, seq.relname as seq_name
from pg_class as seq
join pg_namespace ns on (seq.relnamespace=ns.oid)
where seq.relkind = 'S'
  and not exists (select * from pg_depend where objid=seq.oid and deptype='a')
order by seq.relname;
 schema_name |            seq_name            
-------------+--------------------------------
 public      | non_existing_table_id_seq
 public      | another_non_existing_table_id_seq
(2 rows)
```

The command which should fix this issue doesn't run because `column d.adsrc does not exist`
It seems to have been removed from postgres-12.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/58798028/1891184 says I can replace `d.adsrc` with `pg_get_expr(d.adbin, d.adrelid)`. and that runs, however the issue still remains.

Other than this, the database is working fine.

How can I either fix or remove the offending sequences in order to let pg_dump work?

Comment: `DROP SEQUENCE IF EXISTS non_existing_table_id_seq;` errors with:
`ERROR:  catalog is missing 3 attribute(s) for relid 74471446`

Comment: That looks like metadata corruption. Did you mess with the catalogs manually? Hire a PostgreSQL expert to fix that.